# Get regular expression matched positon?

Tags: regex, r

Here is a string :

```
str1="ha,hihi,aaaaa,ok"
```

I want to get the position of `","` in the `str1`,Which can count `3,8,14`.
how can I get it in R ?

Answer (score 5):

You get the desired vector using this expression:

```
as.integer(gregexpr(",", str1)[[1]])
```

The `[[1]]` will choose the first element of the resulting list. If `str1` were a vector of a length other than 1, then `gregexpr` would result a list with that many items, one for each element of `str1`.

The `as.integer` will strip additional attributes, like the length of the matched text. In many situations you will be able to omit this, as other code will likely simply ignore those attributes. For output to the console it might be less confusing, though, so I included it in my answer.